How to scale marker on Google Map smoothly?
I want to scale marker on Google Map, my code works but in some devices marker will disappear a few times, anyone know how to scale smoothly?
I tried use ValueAnimator to set marker's icon:
val choreographer = Choreographer.getInstance()
                val desiredFrameRate = 20
                val frameInterval = 1000L / desiredFrameRate
                var lastFrameTime = 0L

                val widthAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(anim.fromX, anim.toX)
                widthAnimator.duration = anim.duration
                widthAnimator.repeatMode = anim.repeatMode
                widthAnimator.repeatCount = anim.repeatCount

                val heightAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(anim.fromY, anim.toY)
                heightAnimator.duration = anim.duration
                heightAnimator.repeatMode = anim.repeatMode
                heightAnimator.repeatCount = anim.repeatCount

                val animatorUpdateListener = ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {
                    val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    if (currentTime - lastFrameTime < frameInterval) {
                        return@AnimatorUpdateListener
                    }
                    lastFrameTime = currentTime
                    choreographer.postFrameCallback { choreographerTime ->
                        val scaleX =
                            BigDecimal((widthAnimator.animatedValue as Float).toDouble()).setScale(
                                3,
                                RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN
                            ).toFloat()
                        val scaleY =
                            BigDecimal((heightAnimator.animatedValue as Float).toDouble()).setScale(
                                3,
                                RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN
                            ).toFloat()
                        marker.setIcon(
                            createScaledBitmapDescriptor(
                                viewToDrawable(target), scaleX, scaleY
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
                heightAnimator.addUpdateListener(animatorUpdateListener)
                animations.apply {
                    add(widthAnimator)
                    add(heightAnimator)
                }


use ObjectAnimator without adding additional time checks
use AnimatorSet for better frame rendering
avoid frequent icon changes
bitmap caching

thanks, but it doesn't work for me. I cannot get marker's view and I think ObjectAnimator depends on reflection so that it is not as good as ValueAnimator.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
